# Economics Question - Days Forward Coverage Formula

Tags: economics

I am trying to replicate a built-in function in our application that calculates Days Forward Coverage (How many days can your supply fulfill demands in a given horizon).

I know how to arrive at the desired result which is by manually counting the number of days and now I am trying to figure out what the formula would be to get to the desired result based on the data below.

| Current Inventory | Total Demand | Total Supply | Horizon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 523,843 | 1,442,280 | 1,643,843 | 361 days |

The built-in function that we have shows that the `Current Inventory` would be able to fulfill future demands for the next `82.81` days.

I'm trying to find what would be the formula that could get me `82.81` days, but no luck so far and I've been stuck on this problem for a week now.

Comment: On the surface, it doesn't look as if we have enough information here. What is "Total Supply", say, as opposed to "Inventory"?  Is there a way to meet Demand that doesn't draw from Inventory?  And, more directly to the point, how long will unmet Demand wait?  Presumably the authors of this app have a lot of history to draw from, but we have  none.

Comment: My apologies. The Total supply is the Current Inventory + all the supplies that would come within the given horizon. All Demands would be deducted from the Current Inventory. It doesn't really matter how long a Demand has to wait before it could be fulfilled.

Comment: Well then, the rate at which "Supply" is converted to "Inventory" is critical.  If $100\%$ of Supply is instantly converted to Inventory, you have more than enough to meet all of the Demand.  So, presumably, the issue is that it takes time to create more Inventory.

Comment: Cheap observation:  Current inventory is a bit more than $36\%$ of Demand, so if we spread Demand uniformly over the year, you could meet demand for about $131$ days without converting anything from Supply.  So...somehow you are heavily frontloading demand (which is why I asked if Demand had some kind of time stamp on it).

Comment: Yes, the Demands fall on different days across the given horizon. We can see that the current Inventory of 523,843 can only cover the demands for the next 82.81 days (which has a total demand of 526,008) and the next 277 days has a total demand of 916,272.

Comment: But, of course, we have no information at all on the time distribution of Demand.  That's very precise information which, presumably, is derived from knowledge of your business (beach side hotels experience much greater demand in the summer, say).  We don't have this information.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your feedback. Really appreciate it. I'll try to think of another way to attain the results that I need.